# Entity framework where clause

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am newbie to EF how to use and - or in where clause in the entity framework

```
HR_ATTENDANCE_DEVICE_SHUTDOWN_TBL attendanceDeviceShutdownTbl = 
    context.HR_ATTENDANCE_DEVICE_SHUTDOWN_TBL
        .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Device_ID.Equals(model.DeviceId) &&
                             x=>x.Device_Name=model.DeviceName);
```

the above code will not work but how can I make it works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Expression lambda has following syntax `param => expression`. I.e. its like simple method, which have input parameter(s) and body. You define parameters only once and then use them in body of method or lambda:

```
HR_ATTENDANCE_DEVICE_SHUTDOWN_TBL attendanceDeviceShutdownTbl = 
    context.HR_ATTENDANCE_DEVICE_SHUTDOWN_TBL.FirstOrDefault(x => 
        x.Device_ID.Equals(model.DeviceId) && x.Device_Name == model.DeviceName);
```

In this case you have single parameter `x` which *goes to* anonymous function body. Body is an expression which should return boolean value and (usually) use parameter `x`. In your case lambda body should be

```
x.Device_ID.Equals(model.DeviceId) && x.Device_Name == model.DeviceName
```

Suggested reading: [Lambda Expressions (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx). Also note `==` is a comparison operator. `=` is an assignment operator. Do not mix up with them.